# Increase size of square brackets

Tags: matrices

How can I increase the size of the brackets? They are not enclosing the whole matrix.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]

\begin{spacing}{0.5}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}


    \[ \mathbf{\hat R }= \begin{blockarray}{r*{5}{ >{\color{black}}c}}
    & A & B & C & D & E \\
    \begin{block}{ >{\scriptstyle}r!{\,}[ccccc]}
    1 & 5 & 3.09  & 4.90 & - & \textbf{4.62} \\
    2 & - & 2.89 & 4.69  & \textbf{3.49}  & 4.42 \\
    3 & 4.10 & 2.19 & - & \textbf{2.78}  & 3.71 \\
    4 & - & \textbf{1.00} & 2.49 & 1.29  & 2.22  \\
    5 & 4.90 & - & \textbf{4.79} & 3.58   & 4.51 \\
    6 & \textbf{4.88} & 2.96 & - & 3.56  & 4.48 \\
    7 & 3.15 & \textbf{1.23} & 3.03 & 1.82  & - \\
    8 & 4.84 & \textbf{2.92} & 4.72 & -  & 4.61 \\
    9 & \textbf{4.84} & 2.92 & 4.72 & 3.51  & - \\ 
    10& \textbf{4.61} & - & 4.49 & 3.29  & 4.22 \\
    \end{block}
    \end{blockarray} \]%

\end{spacing}
\caption{}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How or where is the `spacing` environment defined?

Comment: I have edited the OP

Comment: The macros and environments of the `setspace` package are meant to be employed n text mode. It's asking for trouble to use a `spacing` environment inside a display-math environment. Don't do it. Instead, insert the instruction  `\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}`  immediately after `\[`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you. It worked but now the numbers look very close to each other. That's why I used `spacing` before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, increasing the total height of the square brackets should be the least of your (typographic) priorities. I'd focus most (all?) of my energy on telling TeX to use the regular-bold rather than (default) bold-extended font weight for the numbers in the five data columns. I would also expend some energy on increasing the horizontal separation between the tall `[` and `]` symbols and the columns they enclose. In the code shown below, that's accomplished with the `>{\,}` and `<{\,}` particles.

Oh, and don't use a `spacing` environment inside a display-math setting. If you absolutely, positively *must* shrink the distance between rows, reset the parameter `\arraystretch` to a value less than `1`. In the example shown below, I use a value of `0.5` -- which, in my opinion, is much too small. Do try something like `0.8` or `0.9` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}
\[ 
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}   % use bold, not bold-extended
\renewcommand\arraystretch{.5} % choose a suitable factor
\widehat{\mathbf{R}}= 
\begin{blockarray}{@{} r *{5}{c} }
      & A & B & C & D & E \\
    \begin{block}{@{} >{\scriptscriptstyle}r [>{\,}ccccc<{\,}] }
    1 & 5.00 & 3.09  & 4.90 & - & \textbf{4.62} \\
    2 & - & 2.89 & 4.69  & \textbf{3.49} & 4.42 \\
    3 & 4.10 & 2.19 & - & \textbf{2.78}  & 3.71 \\ 
    4 & - & \textbf{1.00} & 2.49 & 1.29  & 2.22 \\
    5 & 4.90 & - & \textbf{4.79} & 3.58  & 4.51 \\
    6 & \textbf{4.88} & 2.96 & - & 3.56  & 4.48 \\
    7 & 3.15 & \textbf{1.23} & 3.03 & 1.82 & -  \\
    8 & 4.84 & \textbf{2.92} & 4.72 & -  & 4.61 \\
    9 & \textbf{4.84} & 2.92 & 4.72 & 3.51 & -  \\ 
    10& \textbf{4.61} & - & 4.49 & 3.29  & 4.22 \\
    \end{block}
    \end{blockarray} 
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a workaround for the brackets size: use `\bigtrut[t]` in a cell of the first row and `\bigstrut[b]` in the last row. I added a simplication of the code for the first column, using the `BAenum` row counter defined by the package Last, I removed the unnecessary colon after the figure label, since there's no caption text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]\bigstrutjot=1ex \captionsetup{labelsep=none, skip=0pt}
    \[ \mathbf{\widehat R }=\begin{blockarray}{r*{5}{ >{\color{black}}c}}
    & A & B & C & D & E \\\noalign{\setcounter{BAenumi}{1}}
    \begin{block}{ >{\scriptstyle\theBAenumi}r!{\,}[ccccc]}
    & 5 & 3.09 & 4.90 & - & \mathbf{4.62}\bigstrut[t] \\
    & - & 2.89 & 4.69 & \mathbf{3.49} & 4.42 \\
    & 4.10 & 2.19 & - & \mathbf{2.78} & 3.71 \\
    & - & \mathbf{1.00} & 2.49 & 1.29 & 2.22 \\
    & 4.90 & - & \mathbf{4.79} & 3.58 & 4.51 \\
    & \mathbf{4.88} & 2.96 & - & 3.56 & 4.48 \\
    & 3.15 & \mathbf{1.23} & 3.03 & 1.82 & - \\
    & 4.84 & \mathbf{2.92} & 4.72 & - & 4.61 \\
    & \mathbf{4.84} & 2.92 & 4.72 & 3.51 & - \\
    & \mathbf{4.61} & - & 4.49 & 3.29 & 4.22 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \end{block}
    \end{blockarray} \]%
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It does look fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: It does not work properly when I compile my whole TeX document. Check this post, which has your example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/512381/194319

Comment: Which post do you mean?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/512381/194319

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [`kbordermatrix`](//ctan.org/pkg/kbordermatrix):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kbordermatrix}

\begin{document}

\[ 
  \renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}   % use bold, not bold-extended
  \widehat{\mathbf{R}} = 
  \kbordermatrix{%
       &   A  &   B  &   C  & D & E \\
    1  & 5.00 & 3.09 & 4.90 & - & \textbf{4.62}  \\
    2  & - & 2.89 & 4.69  & \textbf{3.49} & 4.42 \\
    3  & 4.10 & 2.19 & - & \textbf{2.78}  & 3.71 \\
    4  & - & \textbf{1.00} & 2.49 & 1.29  & 2.22 \\
    5  & 4.90 & - & \textbf{4.79} & 3.58  & 4.51 \\
    6  & \textbf{4.88} & 2.96 & - & 3.56  & 4.48 \\
    7  & 3.15 & \textbf{1.23} & 3.03 & 1.82 & -  \\
    8  & 4.84 & \textbf{2.92} & 4.72 & -  & 4.61 \\
    9  & \textbf{4.84} & 2.92 & 4.72 & 3.51 & -  \\
    10 & \textbf{4.61} & - & 4.49 & 3.29  & 4.22
  }
\]

\end{document}
```

The above code is taken partially from [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512255/5764).

Comment: When I run it, it throws this error `File `kbordermatrix.sty' not found. ^^M`

Comment: @Delan: Download [`kbordermatrix.sty`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/misc/kbordermatrix.sty) and store it in `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\local` - do you have TeX Live? Then run `texhash` from the command prompt. Alternatively, just download `kbordermatrix.sty` and place it in your working folder.